# 64bit Excel Office 2010: Automation error %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Tags: excel, automation, 64-bit, excel-2010, vba

This function works on Microsoft Office 32bit. But when transferring to 64bit, the error "Automation error %1 is not a valid Win32 application" occured.

```
Private Function CreateUsingManifest(nameOfClass As String) As Object
    Dim actCtx As Object

    Set actCtx = CreateObject("Microsoft.Windows.ActCtx")


    On Error GoTo InvalidManifest
    Set CreateUsingManifest = actCtx.CreateObject(nameOfClass) 'Error here

    Set actCtx = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

InvalidManifest:
    Err.Raise  "Automation error %1 is not a valid Win32 application."
End Function
```

Comment: You are hard coding that error message - what is the actual contents of Err.Description when you get to the error handler?

Comment: That is the actual error, I just put it like that to see what the error will return

Comment: Can you explain _when transferring to 64bit_ ? Have you copied your XLSM file on to a different 64 bit computer? Or have you upgraded your existing Office / OS ?

Comment: I'm using a 64bit OS right now. I installed here first my 32bit MS Office and it was working fine. Then I uninstalled it and replaced it with a 64bit MS Office and this error "Automation error %1 is not a valid Win32 application." pops up.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I can help further but can I suggest you change your error handler to `MsgBox Err.Description` or remove it altogether to save confusion.